# Opportunity coming back to Eloqua doesn't display campaign contribution means campaign name?

Tags: integration, sales

I have integrated Eloqua with Sales using cx Sales integration app after the creation of campaign from Eloqua to Sales and after creating lead and contact turning that lead into an opportunity, and status is won then that opportunity comes back to Eloqua with an amount for Closeloop reporting, but it does not display contributing campaign related to that opportunity. Contributing Campaigns due to this in campaign metric we can't see the amount like rol report, some time it comes and some time it not coming

all the images
[image]